# Extjs 4.X RowEditor trigger 'update' button

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, roweditor

The RowEditor plugin on my grid works well but for one my use case I have to trigger the 'update' button programmatically and close the popped up RowEditor panel.  For reference, below screenshot:

[image]

I have tried below command but it does not seem to trigger the event.

```
var updtBtn = grid.getPlugin('myPlugin').editor.floatingButtons.child('#update');
myBtn.fireEvent('click', myBtn);
```

I have created a fiddle to test this:
[fiddle for RowEditor update firevent](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/330n)

The above command (which did not work) gets executed on below steps:

1. Click on a row to edit, change the text, do not close the editor popup.
2. Now click on the 'Add' button on the grid header, which will add a row. This is also when update button fire event need to trigger as per the command I used.

Any pointers on how to get this working is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your edit complete you need to use `grid.getPlugin('myPlugin').editor.completeEdit();` instead of `myBtn.fireEvent('click', myBtn);`.

Look on fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/330o

Comment: Thank you very much, It works. Now I just need to configure store proxy to make this event post to backend.